# Android SDK Tools(Obsolete)

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am installing Android Studio on my Mac running Catalina OS. I have been getting an error from flutter doctor saying `` Android `sdkmananger` tool not found `` I double-checked my path is correct so I went and found out the reason I am getting this error is because the Android SDK is not installing the tools directory. So after looking around a little, I see it is marked as obsolete in the SDK tools tab.

My questions are is the correct course of action to just go ahead and install it.

Secondly, why is this marked as obsolete if flutter is still configured to look for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reasonable approach, for now, is what you did. People on other channels are getting the same [error](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51670) and their solution is the same. See this GitHub [comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51670#issuecomment-592943797).

I think it is a temporary issue, since flutter team already [addressed](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51712#issuecomment-595487979) this.